# SetTitle to a button and back to the first title again when clicked twice

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I managed to change the title of a button itself and the text of a label by clicking on it. 
On the top of that, I would like the title of the same button and the same text in the label to change AGAIN when clicked for the second time. Considering the code that I already build, how could I add that?

```
@IBOutlet weak var changeDegreeDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var radPressed: UIButton!

@IBAction func radianPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        radPressed.setTitle("Deg", forState: .Normal)
        changeDegreeDisplay.text = "radians"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably would want to use an if statement to check for the current title of the button or its state, depends on your use case.

```
@IBAction func radianPressed(sender: UIButton) {
  if sender.currentTitle == "Deg" {
    sender.setTitle("Rad", forState: .Normal)
  } else {
    sender.setTitle("Deg", forState: .Normal)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the title of the button, and check to see if it's "Deg" or "Rad", and then switch it to the correct one.

```
@IBOutlet weak var changeDegreeDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var radPressed: UIButton!

@IBAction func radianPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let title = radPressed.titleForState(.Normal)
    if title=="Deg" {
        radPressed.setTitle("Rad", .Normal)
        changeDegreeDisplay.text = "degrees"
    } else {
        radPressed.setTitle("Deg", .Normal)
        changeDegreeDisplay.text = "radians"
    }
}
```

I would suggest storing the titles as constants, so `let degTitle = "Deg"` and `let radTitle = "Rad"`, and then compare using these constants in the conditional.